# How do paths work in a Java deployed REST web service?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jax-rs

Under **Tomcat** and **Jersey** libraries I created a REST web service described in this class:

```
package Servicios;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("service")
public class ServiceResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of ServiceResource
     */
    public ServiceResource() {
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getHtml() {

        return "<h1>Here we are, at the contemplation of the most simple web service</h1>";
    }

    @PUT
    @Consumes("text/html")
    public void putHtml(String content) {
    }
}
```

So, as I set it before accessing to `http://localhost:8080/GetSomeRest` makes the default created `.jsp` file created.

I set in project propierties (using NetBeans) a *relative URL* as `webresources/service`, so `service` part is same defined in `@Path("service")`. All works ok, going to `http://localhost:8080/GetSomeRest/webresources/service` makes the web service be consumed.

But what if I want to *consume* that service right from `http://localhost:8080/GetSomeRest/service`? I tried to set only `service` in such relative URL and I got an `Error 404` message going to `http://localhost:8080/GetSomeRest/service`

How do virtual paths work?

What would it mean to add an alias to a web service?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking. Are you asking how relative URLs work? Are you asking how to set up an alias in your web service? It's very confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path segment `webresources` is not set in the code you provide so I will guess what your code looks like.

A JAX-RS application can be configured with a class extending `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`. Such a class can be annotated with `@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath()`. My guess is that in your project this annotation is set to

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
```

So the URL of a `JAX-RS` resource class is build from these parts.

1. `http://localhost:8080/` - host and port
2. `GetSomeRest` -  the context, normally the name of the deployed `.war` file
3. `webresources` - the value of the `@ApplicationPath` annotation
4. `service` - the value of the `@Path` annotation of the class

I recommend *not* to skip step 3.

The value of the `@ApplicationPath` annotation can be overridden by a `servlet-mapping` element in the `web.xml`.

Comment: Where is that `web.xml` supposed to be?

Comment: The `web.xml` is optional in the direcotry `/WEB-INF/`.

Comment: What is that file supposed to define? Why is it optional?

Answer (score 0):

Just for information

The path segment `webresources` 
 is set in the code by netbeans in the package

**org.netbeans.rest.application.config - ApplicationConfig Class**  into your own project!!! so change it and it's done...